# Solr search result is wrong when indexd product code contains special character(%)

Tags: solr, lucene, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a product with the code having special character **eg:abc-3%-100** .

I have indexed and search with **100** .The solr Query is written to search like **100***.The search gives proper result ("*no product found with search 100*" assuming I have only this product) when I remove **"%"** from the product code.

I am unable to understand why solr is returning this product for search text 100 when product has % in it's code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for exact match then you can go for the string field type for your field which are using for searching.

If you use the tokenizer.. It will create the tokens depending on how their are written.

As you are using keyword tokenizer.. It will not create any tokens of the same.

Benefit of using the above tokenizer is ...you can also use some other filters like stopword and lowercase etc...

Stopword filter will help you to remove the words like ...is,the,are etc..which are very common and does not make any sense for indexing...

Lowercase filter converts the text in lower case while indexing and searching.

Stopword filter is not applicable in current case .

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this. I have changed the ***tokenizer*** value from StandardTokenizerFactory into KeywordTokenizerFactory for the solr type